# Selenium - TestNG - How to skip/disable some tests according to parametr passed by Maven commandline in paralle use

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, listener

we have a multinational site. Not all functionality is available everywhere ie. in all countries (languages). I have a few hundreds tests build on stack Java - TestNG - TestNG listeners - Selenium WebDriver (Page object model) - Maven. All tests are running from Jenkins using Maven and commandline. Using commandline I'm passing all neccessary parameters ie. test groups, baseURL, language, etc.

Some of tests are running parallely, some of tests singlethread. From that reason I have `testng.xml` set like this:

```
<suite name="Tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestListener"/>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestSuiteListener"/>
        <listener class-name="listeners.SkipInCountryMethodInterceptorListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Parallel tests" parallel="methods" thread-count="8">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Parallel" />
                <exclude name="SingleThread" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="tests" />
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="Single thread tests" parallel="false">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="SingleThread" />
                <exclude name="Parallel" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="tests" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

All tests are using groups in Test annotation sorted out.

```
@Test(testName = "testName", priority = Priority.MEDIUM, groups = {TestGroup.SMOKE, TestGroup.SINGLETHREAD})
public void testName () {

}
```

I'm reading commandline parameters in `@BeforeSuite` and I'm putting into attribute of `ITestContext`

```
@BeforeSuite()
@Parameters({ "lang" })
public void beforeSuite(final ITestContext testContext, @Optional("en") String lang) {
...
        testContext.setAttribute("Language", lang);
...
}
```

I tried many ways how according this parameter `lang` (country) filter tests like `@BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {TestGroup.SKIP_IN_EN})` and `SkipException` or using `IAnnotationTransformer` and `setEnable(false)`. I have no clue, how to pass parameter to the `transformer` and use it for a condition. There is no `ITestContext` and it looks like is `transformer` called before `@BeforeSuite`, so before I'm able to read comandline attributes.

What is partly working to me is `IMethodInterceptor`. I've created a new test groups SkipIn[Language] like `SkipInHU`, `SkipInEN`, ... what say, that this test method should be skipped

```
public class SkipInCountryMethodInterceptorListener implements IMethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        List<IMethodInstance> result = new ArrayList<IMethodInstance>();
        for (IMethodInstance method : methods) {
            Test testMethod = method.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(Test.class);
            Set<String> groups = new HashSet<String>();
            for (String group : testMethod.groups()) {
                groups.add(group);
            }

            String language = "en";

            Set<String> attrs = context.getAttributeNames();
            if (attrs.contains("Language")) {
                try {
                    language = context.getAttribute("Language").toString();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
            }

            if (groups.contains(TestGroup.SKIP_IN_EN) && language.equals("en")) {
                Log.info("TestMethod skipped.");
            } else {
                result.add(method);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

But this solution has a problem in a parallel run of tests. I don't know why, maybe different threads, but `@BeforeSuite` isn't able to put attribute into `ITestContext`. In `IMethodInterceptor` is everytime attribute of ITestContext empty (attribute Language is `null`, not exist),and only `@BeforeClass` works good (read maven parameters), but this is after `IMethodInterceptor` is already called.

What is the best idea to filter tests for countries?

I can say, that 90% of tests is global, so it's not a good aproach, from my point of view, to have a test group for every country and pass a group of tests I want to run. Because on one test I have to have maybe 10 different groups yet and with every new country I should have added new test group to each test.

Thanks for help or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IAnnotationTransformer`. For example here is my test class:

```java
public class TestSkip {

    @Test(testName = "ruTest", groups = {"RU_TESTS"})
    public void ruTest(){
        System.out.println("Running RU test");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test(testName = "enTest", groups = {"EN_TESTS"})
    public void enTest(){
        System.out.printf("Running EN test");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

And here is my `testng.xml`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="click.webelement.testng.TestSkipTransformer"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="SO-answer">
        <packages>
            <package name="click.webelement.testng" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here is my annotation transformer implementation:

```java
public class TestSkipTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        String language = System.getProperty("lang", "EN");
        if ("EN".equals(language)
                && !Arrays.asList(annotation.getGroups()).contains("EN_TESTS")) {
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if ("RU".equals(language)
                && !Arrays.asList(annotation.getGroups()).contains("RU_TESTS")) {
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my surefire settings where I set the parameter (not to deal with command line args)

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <lang>RU</lang>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```